# ASP.NET MVC DropDownList displaying "Id" instead of "Description"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been doing some tutorials in ASP.NET MVC and decided to try something I hadn't seen yet.

I have two tables: Patient and Classification. I want to be able to create a new Classification, then when I Create or Edit a new Patient, I can choose a Classification.

Right now, as an example of what I have in my DropDownList, lets say I have cat, dog and fish. If I select cat, the value displayed will be 1 instead of the actual word "cat."

My question is can this be achieved with the code I have or does it need a complete rewrite? And if you have any other general suggestions let me know.

My Controller:

```
private PatientContext db = new PatientContext();
private ClassificationContext dbCC = new ClassificationContext();

    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PatientId,First_Name,Last_Name,Address,City,State,Zipcode,Phone,ClassificationId")] Patient patient)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Patients.Add(patient);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.Classifications = new SelectList(dbCC.Classifications, "ClassificationId", "Description");
        return View(patient);
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Patient patient = db.Patients.Find(id);
        if (patient == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        ViewBag.Classifications = new SelectList(dbCC.Classifications, "ClassificationId", "Description");

        return View(patient);
    }
```

Patient Model:

```
public class Patient
{
    public int PatientId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Classification")]
    public int ClassificationId { get; set; }
}
```

Classification Model:

```
public class Classification
{
    public int ClassificationId { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Create (Patient) View:

```
        <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassificationId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassificationId)*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClassificationId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Classifications, "Select Classification")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassificationId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Edit (Patient) View:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ClassificationId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ClassificationId)*@
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ClassificationId,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Classifications, "Select Classification")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClassificationId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

Index (Patient) View:

```
        <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ClassificationId)
       </td>
```

Comment: Are your drop down values showing the number instead of the word or just your patient view? You are using item.ClassificationId instead of item.Description in that view.

Comment: The actual word appears in the drop down list. I'm unable to use item.Description in the Patient view and so that every well may be the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to distinguish between the `SelectListItem.Text` (which is displayed in the dropdown) and the `SelectListItem.Value` (which is the value bound to your model)

Replacing the line in your controller defining `ViewBag.Classifications` with something like this:

```
ViewBag.Classifications = dbCC.Classifications
  .Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c.ClassificationId, Text = c.Description })
  .ToList();
```

ought to do it.